# XSD schema to validate all elements using a common restriction pattern: e.g. allowable characters

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I have a number of complex XSD files used to validate incoming XMLs. These XSDs are standards and get updated once in a while.

On top of that, there is a business restriction dictating that only a specific subset of latin characters, numbers and symbols should be allowed in any element/attribute.

Instead of going to each XSD and add a pattern restriction to each and every simpleType (this is impossible for a number of reasons), my idea is to create a common XSD that will be used as a general validation before the specific XSD validation will be applied.

However, I can't find a way to apply the same restriction to a variable set of elements, no matter where and how deep they are declared.

To give you an idea, I thought of using `xsd:any` and apply the same `simpleType` like so:

```
<!-- XSD for allowable characters -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="AppHdr" type="AnyRoot"/>

    <xs:simpleType name="AnyElement">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[A-Za-z0-9]*"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:complexType name="AnyRoot">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:any namespace="##any" processContents="skip"
                    minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"
                    type="AnyElement"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Unfortunatelly, there is no `type` attribute allowed in `xs:any` so this is not valid. Maybe this with a combination of `xs:group` could do the trick?

Searched for any alternative but with no luck, all similar approached I've found involve changing specific elements in the original XSDs with known names and locations. This is a **no-go** for me.

At first, it seemed pretty trivial and common case in my mind but it turned out to be a rare scenario.

I'll appreciate if anyone could shed some light to it. Thanks!

[EDIT]:

I finally decided to follow another path instead of XSD, I'm using XSL to filter invalid characters and get a report back if found.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- XSL for allowable characters: Andreas Gounaris, 2021 -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:devdom="http://example.com/xfunctions/"
                extension-element-prefixes="devdom">
    <xsl:output method="text" media-type="text/plain" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <!-- Matching document root -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="verify"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Remove whitespace between nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="text()[not(normalize-space())]" mode="verify"/>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="verify">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="verify"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Matching attribute and text nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | text()" mode="verify">
        <xsl:variable name="invalidContent" select="devdom:exslt_verify_mx_disclosure_chars(.)"/>
        <xsl:if test="$invalidContent">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(parent::*), ': ', $invalidContent)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="'|-|'"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The transformer goes through all attributes and text nodes and calls a XSLT external function `exslt_verify_mx_disclosure_chars` with the current node as a param.
The function matches any but valid chars from a regex.

In this example, I'm returning a str-delimited text file '|-|' but it could be an XML as well.

Comment: Does it have to be an XSD 1 schema? Or could you use Schematron or could you use XSD 1.1 with assertions?

Comment: @MartinHonnen You mean 2 XSDs for the first validation (allowable chars)? As for your other suggestions, I'd prefer not to put other frameworks into the picture that will add extra effort (learning curve, implementation, resources) as this process is a small part in an extremely demanding messaging service pipeline. Thank you for your suggestions, I'll have a look.

Comment: Well, I'm thinking, as a last resort, to write a small piece of XSLT to transform the XML and output a success message or a list of problematic elements if validation fails. However, I'd like to know if this is possible using XSD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schematron using XPath or XSLT 2 or 3 might be like

```
<schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" queryBinding="xslt2">
    <pattern>
        <rule context="text()[normalize-space()] | @*">
            <assert test="matches(., '^[A-Za-z0-9]*$')">Only ASCII characters and digits</assert>
        </rule>
    </pattern>
</schema>
```

Comment: This is perfect, it's a combination of xsl and xsd, if only was the case without Schematron (large footprint). I'm voting for this as a valid answer, although my solution went through XSLT and a custom extension function (see my edits above).

Comment: @Agoun, as you seem to use XSLT 2 where you have regular expression support without the need to use extension functions I don't quite understand why you need that in your approach. As for Schematron extending the toolchain, yes, I understand that it would be desirable to solve it with XSD schemas only, but I couldn't see a way and Michael Kay's answer suggests he didn't see one either. As for only using XSLT, in XSLT 3 there is an `xsl:assert` instruction in addition to the XSLT 1 and 2 `xsl:message`, so it should certainly be possible to eliminate Schematron and have diagnostics with XSLT.

Comment: Well, i missed this 'matches' function in XSLT 2, thanks. The thing I have to check is how to pass the regex as a param. Escaped or not? Regex should be taken from the system. ```xsl:message``` writes to stdout so I have to catch this as well.

Answer (score 2):

If this is mixed content then you definitely can't do it (without XSD 1.1 assertions) - there's no way of restricting the text that appears in mixed content.

With simple types, you could make all the (string-based) simple types derive from a subtype of xs:string with the appropriate pattern restriction, but if that's too much refactoring for your taste, then you're going to have to find another way.

If you're going to do a separate validation pass independent of your XSD validation, then XSD doesn't seem the right technology to do it. If you're in the Java world I'd be tempted to do it using a SAX filter placed between the XML parser and the schema validator.

Comment: Michael, thank you, indeed I didn't find anything involving XSD other than messing with the prototypes and I won't do that. However, I figured out a way that is easy (for those who can handle xslt and external functions) and it is applied to any kind of XML, regardless namespaces. Moreover, it returns a list of elements failing this validation (invalid chars) so that the system can gracefully handle and notify what and where issues are spotted. I'll post my solution as soon as I find some free time.